# Can't find RavenDB Dynamic Queries

Tags: c#, ravendb

I just started trying out RavenDB and it seems that the new/easy way to do queries is to use dynamic instead of canned.  I downloaded build 191 but Query needs takes a parameter that is the index name.  How do I enable dynamic queries?  Am I missing a namespace?  Do I need a version newer than 191?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right.

Build 191 is indeed the latest un-stable build, I just downloaded it to sanity check my answer before giving it - I don't know what binaries you're looking at though because I have indeed got

```
session.Query<Entity>()
```

Which is how you use dynamic queries (IE, not specifying an index name)

I've made sure that both the EmbeddedClient, the .NET 3.5 binaries and the standard lightweight client have this functionality.

My only answer is therefore that you must be looking at old versions of the binaries?

Comment: Thanks, you were correct.  For some reason VS.NET was referencing an old dll in my bin/debug folder